# Why onTapGesture is called after clicking on empty space in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I can't figure out why when clicking between elements, the handler is called in onTapGesture. Am I doing something wrong?

```
    struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 15) {
            ForEach(0 ..< 5) { item in
                Color.red
                    .frame(height: 50)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        print(item)
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to set spacing 50 and handler is not invoked when clicking in the middle of the empty space, but handler of nearest element is invoked  when I clicked at the top or bottom part of the empty space

as if the element still has an invisible area slightly wider than the visible one

Comment: I tried your code and it works perfectly fine. Do you use the latest Xcode version?

Comment: Xcode version: Version 12.3 (12C33)